# how to add line break inside color command

Tags: color

I am writing this script:

```
\begin{chronology}[5]{1993}{2016}{\textwidth} [\textwidth] 
\event{\decimaldate{25}{3}{2011}}{\textcolor{red} {Line1 \\Line2}}
\end{chronology}
```

However, the `\\` does not make any effect. How to make line break?

**EDIT:**
Here is the full script:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,14pt]{article}
\usepackage{chronology} %for timeline
\begin{document}

\begin{chronology}[5]{1993}{2016}{\textwidth} [\textwidth] 
\event{\decimaldate{25}{3}{2011}}{\textcolor{red} {Line1 \\ Line2}}
\end{chronology}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: Of course line breaks do work inside `\textcolor`, see `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}
\textcolor{red}{Line1 \\Line2} 
\end{document}`. So you have to reveal where your other commands are coming from.

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with the textcolour, but with the `\event` from `\chronology`. As a quick hack, just place the text inside a `parbox`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,14pt]{article}
\usepackage{chronology} %for timeline
\begin{document}

\begin{chronology}[5]{1993}{2016}{\textwidth} [\textwidth] 
\event{\decimaldate{25}{3}{2011}}{\textcolor{red}{%
        \parbox[c]{3cm}{Line1 \\ Line2}
}}
\end{chronology}

\end{document}
```

[image]